# I haven't been paid in over a month, and he's now claiming that TODAY I violated a gag order

Tags: united-states, contracts

I was recently hired on with a Co, after it took some work getting my first pay from him (claiming it was am accounting error) AND he only paid me for 1 week, claiming an oversight on his part. It's now been an additional month and no pay. For the last 2 weeks, everyday (including the weekends) he's claimed either him or his "assistant" is "on our way to wire you this money so our issue can be resolved" yet they never do. Stating either traffic, sickness, or just doesn't respond at all for the rest of the day. On the 17th he put my employment on "hold" because I asked when I would be paid. 
Well today, after claiming yet again, that his assistant would wire me the money and didn't, I started doing a more thorough search on him and found another employee from a year ago that still hasn't paid. I spoke with her, and about 20 minutes later, he messaged me saying that I violated a "gag order" in my contract and he would not pay me at all because of this "violation". I have a feeling that somehow, through my work history with him, he was able to obtain my personal passcodes to all my accounts, which is how he knew I contacted her. 
Is any of this legal or has anyone ever heard of an employer doing this? 
I'm in the US

Comment: I apologize then. I guess I'm not asking for legal advice per say, I am mainly wondering if anyone has ever heard of someone claiming a gag order violation after the employer already violated the terms of the employment, (non payment)

Comment: The obvious answer is that yes, some employers have done some pretty shady things.  However that doesn't really help you in any way.  Really, just work through the system, that's what it is there for.

Comment: "I have a feeling that somehow, through my work history with him, he was able to obtain my personal passcodes to all my accounts" - erm... if this is the case, other than being sloppy security on your part, he could be in trouble for accessing your accounts - but for all of this - you need to document everything and then talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Personal passcodes to your accounts? What accounts are you talking about? Like your account with your mobile phone provider?

Answer (score 14):

Contact the Department of Labor of your state ASAP, and explain your situation to them - It's their job to enforce the state labor laws. It looks from your description of your situation that your employer is out to cheat you of your wages. The gag order thing that your employer is using as a justification looks like something that your employer pulled out of his butt.

Comment: Thank you, I did call them and have an appointment to bring proof of my employment next week. I guess I was just a little curious if this was something anyone had heard of before. I've never had an issue with non payment with any company before, this whole thing has put such a strain on my family. I'm sorry if my question wasn't appropriate for this site, Google gave me this site as a recommendation to ask employment questions. I appreciate you taking the time to answer me

Comment: @Lynn i'd also recommend finding a new employer asap (if that's not already a given).  Sucks man, goodluck.